# Play's execution contexts vs scala global

Tags: scala, playframework

How does the execution context from

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

differ from Play's execution contexts:

```
import play.core.Execution.Implicits.{internalContext, defaultContext}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

They are very different.

In Play 2.3.x and prior, `play.core.Execution.Implicits.internalContext` is a `ForkJoinPool` with fixed constraints on size, used internally by Play. You should never use it for your application code. From the docs:

> Play Internal Thread Pool - This is used internally by Play. No application code should ever be executed by a thread in this thread pool, and no blocking should ever be done in this thread pool. Its size can be configured by setting internal-threadpool-size in application.conf, and it defaults to the number of available processors.

Instead, you would use `play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext`, which uses an `ActorSystem`.

In 2.4.x, they both use the same `ActorSystem`. This means that Akka will distribute work among its own pool of threads, but in a way that is invisible to you (other than configuration). Several Akka actors can share the same thread.

`scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` is an `ExecutionContext` defined in the Scala standard library. It is a special `ForkJoinPool` that using the `blocking` method to handle potentially blocking code in order to spawn new threads in the pool. You really shouldn't use this in a Play application, as Play will have no control over it. It also has the potential to spawn *a lot* of threads and use a ton of memory, if you're not careful.

I've written more about `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068064/scala-concurrent-blocking-what-does-it-actually-do/29069021#29069021).

Answer (score 13):

They are the same and point out to the default dispatcher of the underlying actor system in your
Play or Akka or combined application.

##Default Play's Context

```
play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
```

##Play's Internal Context

```
play.core.Execution.Implicits.internalContext
```

##Guice's EC Injected

```
class ClassA @Inject()(config: Configuration)
                           (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {
...
}
```

But this is **different**:

```
scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

Also DB drivers, e.g. if you use slick, may come up with their own Execution Context. Anyway,

---

## Best Practices:

- Don’t use `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` when you are using play or akka framework, in this way you may use more threads than optimum during high load so the performance may decrease.
- Don’t be afraid! use the default dispatcher as much as you want everywhere unless you do some blocking task for example listening on network connection, or reading from db explicitly that makes you “current threed” waiting for the result.
- Start with default executor and if you found Play / Akka not responding well during high load, switch to a new thread pool for time consuming computation tasks.

  - Computational tasks that are taking long time is not usually considered blocking. For example traversing an auto completion tree in the memory. But you may considered them blocking when you want to have your control structures remaining functioning once you have a time taking computational task.
  - The bad thing that may happen when you consider computational tasks as non-blocking is that the play and Akka message dispatcher will be paused when all threads are computing in heavy load. The pros of a separate dispatcher is that the queue processor doesn’t starve. The Cons with separate dispatcher is that you may allocate more threads that optimum and your overall performance will be decreased.
  - The difference is for high load servers, don’t worry for small projects, use the default
- Use `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` when you have no other executor running in your app. Don’t worry this is safe then.
- Once you create Futures, use the default pool, this is the safest way unless you are sure that the future is blocking. Then use a separate pool or use blocking{} structure if possible.
- Create a separate thread pool once

  - You `Await` for a future
  - You call Thread.sleep
  - You are reading a stream/socket/http call
  - Manually querying db with a blocking driver, (usually slick is safe)
  - Schedule a task to be run in 10 second
  - Schedule a task to be run every second
- For map/recover operations of a future, use the default executor, usually this is safe
- Exception handling is safe with default dispatcher
- Always use *Akka* dispatchers with you in *Play* or *Akka*, has a nice way to define a new dispatcher in `application.conf`

Answer (score 1):

PRELUDE: This question is from 6 years ago, since then many things have changed. I know this is not an answer to the original question, but I was fooled more than 1 day with the same confusion that the original question states; so I decided to share my research results with the community.

The latest update reagrding ExecutionContext, which perfectly applies to Play 2.8.15 is as follows. The [Play 2.6 migration guide states](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution-is-deprecated):

> The play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution class has been deprecated, as it was using global mutable state under the hood to pull the “current” application’s ExecutionContext.
> If you want to specify the implicit behavior that you had previously, then you should pass in the execution context implicitly in the constructor.

So you cannot use `play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext` anymore. The no-configuration, out-of-the-box practice is to provide an implicit value of type `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext` for the controller, something like:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

@Singleton
class AsyncController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents, actorSystem: ActorSystem)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends AbstractController(cc)
```

This means that none of the above answers hold, also the question itself is not relevant anymore, since `play.core.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext` is not available anymore.

Comment: Neat, thanks! I've not worked with Play for 5 years but this is fascinating to read and useful knowledge sharing. \o/