# Defining the future implicit context in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

In addition to the future's execution context provided by Scala:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

Play provides another execution context:

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
```

When to use each in Play for Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an answer here:

[Play's internal execution context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805337/plays-internal-execution-context)

That question is not complete duplicate but very close, and the answer there cover your question as well.

In a short:

You must not use `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` in Play.

**Response to the comment**

The quote from the answer:

> Instead, you would use
>   `play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext`, which
>   uses an `ActorSystem`.
>
> `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` is an
>   `ExecutionContext` defined in the Scala standard library. It is a
>   special `ForkJoinPool` that using the blocking method to handle
>   potentially blocking code in order to spawn new threads in the pool.
>   You really shouldn't use this in a Play application, as Play will have
>   no control over it. It also has the potential to spawn a lot of
>   threads and use a ton of memory, if you're not careful.

Comment: What I understand from the link is that Play's context is used internally in Play and it should not be used. Therefore, I should use Scala's execution context (not the answer you're telling me)

Comment: please, see the update, I am not sure why you understand it differently

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, if you need an `ExecutionContext` inside a method or class, require it as an implicit parameter (Scala) or a normal parameter (Java). Convention is to put this parameter last.

This rule allows the caller/creator to control where/how/when asynchronous effects are evaluated.

The main exception to this rule is when you already have an `ExecutionContext` and do not wish for the caller/creator to be in control of where the effects are evaluated.